# Django - How to list blog items by their common tags

Tags: python, django, tags, blogs

I'm a django/python beginner working on a basic blog and attempting to list items by their tags. I'm able to add tags to posts from the admin panel, but haven't been able to figure out the proper code that will allow me to display posts by their particular tags.

I have tried to implement many solutions found online, but I've just ended up listing every post, no posts, or gotten errors.

Here is the relevant part of my models.py:

```
... 
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name="default", null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views:

```
...
class TagPage(generic.ListView):
        model = Tag
        template_name = 'tag_list.html'
```

and urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('tag/<slug>/', views.TagPage.as_view(), name='tag')
]
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what code is necessary, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
path('tag/<int:tag_id>/', views.PostView.as_view()
```

views.py

```
class PostView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get)queryset(a*args, **kwargs)
        qs.filter(tags__id=int(self.kwargs['tag_id']))
        return qs
```

post_list.html

```
{% for object in object_list %}
   {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't seemed to be able to get this to solve my issue. When I visit a page with any integer, I am getting a list of all of my post titles.

Comment: Made an edit: try this: qs.filter(tags__id=int(self.kwargs['tag_id']))

Comment: I've tried the edited code, but it still seems to be calling a list of all my post titles.

Comment: It should be creating a list of `Post`s with that `Tag` you've passed.

Comment: The list created looked to be the titles of every post made, not only those with a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a file called `serializers.py` in your app's folder. add this lines of code to that:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Tag
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        Model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then edit your view like this:

```
class TagView(generics.ListAPIView): 
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return Tag.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm getting the error: "TypeError: 'Tag' object is not iterable" when visiting the url. This is the url pattern I have tried:

path('tag/<slug>/', views.TagView.as_view())

Comment: I edited the post and replaced Tags with Tag. try this! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the edited code, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: ok, so i edited code again and replaced get with filter. i think the problem was for that